Add_Cart_Animation in React Native JS
I Need Help,
In my first React Native project, I'm working on a feature where a flat list displays multiple lists, each with an image, text, and addCart Button. When a user taps an addCart Button in this item, I'd like the corresponding image to rotate and fly animate, moving to the cart section in the tab bar. Any suggestions or advice on achieving this in React Native?
React Native Add-Cart-Animation Same Like A flutter add_to_cart_animation: ^2.0.3
https://pub.dev/packages/add_to_cart_animation/example

Try React Native Reanimated and Lottie

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
